# keep parent css when hovering over child item

Tags: css

I am using this CSS code for a horizontal menu:

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 32px;
    background:#F36F25;
    width: auto;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 32px;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a {
    float:left;
    line-height: 32px; 
    color:#fff;
    width: 86px;
    padding: 0 7px;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background:#FFFFFF;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
#nav ul li ul li, #nav ul li ul li a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
}
```

i am trying to get the parent link to stay with the same text color when hovering over a child item. How do i do this? I have also created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gfmxjtr5/1/

Comment: *side note*: avoid using `*` to have better performance in CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set to color of the links when the parent `<li>` is `:hover`ed:

**[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/gfmxjtr5/2/)**

```css
#nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: #000;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 32px;
  background:#F36F25;
  width: auto;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a {
  float:left;
  line-height: 32px; 
  color:#fff;
  width: 86px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
  background:#FFFFFF;
}
#nav ul li:hover > a {
  color:#000;
}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
#nav ul li ul li, #nav ul li ul li a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
}
#nav ul li ul li ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home" class="active">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Account</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="companydetails">Company Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacts">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricetariffs">My Price Tariffs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Billing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="billinginfo">Billing Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="invoices">Invoices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Tickets</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tickets">View Tickets</a></li>
        <li><a href="openticket">Open Ticket</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: brilliant - check this: http://jsfiddle.net/gfmxjtr5/6/ how can i make the child menu text align left?

Comment: @CharlesF Add this `#nav ul li a{text-align:left;}`

Comment: @CharlesF You could either [override](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/gfmxjtr5/7/) the former `text-align: center`declaration by using a more specific seletor: `#nav ul li li a {...}` or [apply](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/gfmxjtr5/8/) the text-align only to the first level links: `#nav > ul > li > a {...}`.